# Send a value between two lists

Tags: list, angularjs

I'm pretty new in angularJS and I have a problem.

This a fiddle to resume my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/ShengTi/RmFYv/

All is good if I send the first value and continue in order.

```
dptRecep : 
[{"text":"Aube","pos":"1"},{"text":"Marne","pos":"2"},{"text":"Haute marne","pos":"3"},{"text":"Bouches du rhone","pos":"4"},{"text":"Aisne","pos":"5"},{"text":"Ain","pos":"6"},{"text":"Aude","pos":"7"}]
```

But if I send the first, then the third etc.. my value go in disorder my array.

```
dptRecep : 
[{"text":"Aube","pos":"1"},{"text":"Bouches du rhone","pos":"4"},{"text":"Marne","pos":"2"},{"text":"Haute marne","pos":"3"},{"text":"Aude","pos":"7"}]
```

May be should I insert my value between the others...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

send only a property `pos` in an each:

```
        <li ng-repeat="item in dpt | orderBy:order:false"> 
            <a href='' ng-click='goToLastList(item.pos)'>
                {{item.pos}} - {{item.text}}
            </a>
        </li>

        ...

        <li ng-repeat="item in dptRecep | orderBy:order:false"> 
            <a href='' ng-click='goToFirstList(item.pos)'>
                {{item.pos}} - {{item.text}}
            </a>
        </li>
```

and then, find the position of an array by pos value:

```
$scope.goToLastList = function (pos) {
    var idx = getIndexByPost($scope.dpt, pos)
    $scope.dptRecep.push($scope.dpt[idx]);
    $scope.dpt.splice(idx, 1);
};

$scope.goToFirstList = function (pos) {
    var idx = getIndexByPost($scope.dptRecep, pos)
    $scope.dpt.push($scope.dptRecep[idx]);
    $scope.dptRecep.splice(idx, 1);
};

function getIndexByPost(array, pos) {
    var rindex = 0
    array.forEach(function(element, index) {
        if (element.pos == pos) rindex = index;
    });
    return rindex;
};
```

for compatibility [Array.prototype.forEach()](http://goo.gl/TZdUU):

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function (fn, scope) {
        'use strict';
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if (i in this) {
                fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

run example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/RmFYv/3/)

Comment: Nice! it works perfectly !
I will see  this code to understand it. Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is wrong. You are pushing the index after you sliced the array. You can just send the item instead, or push before slicing.

plus you can just send item as parameter from your html to angular function.

```
<a href='' ng-click='goToLastList(item, $index)'>{{item.pos}} - {{item.text}}</a>


   $scope.goToLastList = function (item, idx) {
        var dptToMoveList2 = $scope.dpt[idx];
        console.log(dptToMoveList2);
        $scope.dpt.splice(idx,1);
        console.log('idx : '+idx);
        $scope.dptRecep.push(item);
    }
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RmFYv/2/

Comment: if you click the elements on the right of the list they disappear!

Comment: It's because you have to do the same for the elements on the right. This is just a code snippet for the ones on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try sorting after the insertion:

```
$scope.goToLastList = function (item, pos, idx) {
    var dptToMoveList2 = $scope.dpt[idx];
    console.log(dptToMoveList2);
    $scope.dpt.splice(idx,1);
    console.log('idx : '+idx);
    $scope.dptRecep.push({
        text: dptToMoveList2.text,
        pos: dptToMoveList2.pos
    });
    $scope.dptRecep.sort( function (a,b) { return a.pos - b.pos } )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wV3eY/